# how to add PlaneProjection reference to silverlight project?

Tags: silverlight

I'm trying to create silverlight project using eclipse.
i've used PlaneProjection tag in xaml page.

this automatically generated code in CSharp..
there i'm getting error like,

**The type or namespace name 'PlaneProjection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Page.g.cs   /Hekllo/obj/Debug   line 44 Problem Full Build Marker**

what i've understood is there is no reference available here for PlaneProjection.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project must have a reference to `System.Windows.dll`
Typically it can be found here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\vX.X\System.Windows.dll

Comment: yes. the file is available. but i'm unable to display the content in browser